Determining VCdim for union of subspaces $H_i$ - short question
Consider $\mathcal{H} = \mathcal{H}_1 \cup \mathcal{H}_2 \cup \mathcal{H}_3$, where:
$\mathcal{H_1} = \{h_{a} : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \{0,1\} \ | \ h_{a}(x) = 1_{[x \geq a]}(x) = 1_{[a, +\infty)}(x), a \in \mathbb{R}\}$
$\mathcal{H_2} = \{h_{b} : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \{0,1\} \ | \ h_{b}(x) = 1_{[x < b]}(x) = 1_{(-\infty, b)}(x), b \in \mathbb{R}\}$
$\mathcal{H_3} = \{h_{c, d} : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \{0,1\} \ | \ h_{c, d}(x) = 1_{[c \leq x \leq d]}(x) = 1_{[c, d]}(x), c, d \in \mathbb{R}\}$.
Consider the realizability assumption.  Compute VCdim($\mathcal{H}$).
My question is which of the following cases is correct (or am I mistaken):

Should I determine the VCdim for each subspace $H_i, i=1..3$, and then take the highest VCdim, so in this case, VCdim(H) = 2.
Should I consider all intervals on the axis when finding the VCdim, so in this instance, VCdim(H) = 4.

